# what's the meaning of "back-flap"

Tags: american-english, british-english

WHEN members of a private club in Manhattan suddenly start dropping dead at an alarming rate, Matt Scudder, a private detective, suspects more might be at play than bad luck to explain the bizarre series of suicides and violent accidents. If this sounds like the back-flap of a murder mystery, your deduction skills are as sharp as Mr Scudder’s. In Lawrence Block’s “A Long Line of Dead Men,” the cunning detective eventually finds the killer by focusing on what binds the club of 31 men together: they were all part of a tontine.

Comment: The back-flap is part of the paper jacket of the book, which has left inside flap, front, spine, back, and right inside-flap (in order).

Comment: The back-flap is the right inside flap, in case the above isn't clear.  Anyway this was an easy look-up.

Comment: so whats the meaning of the "back-flap " in this sentence, " If this sounds like the back-flap of a murder mystery, your deduction skills are as sharp as Mr Scudder’s."

Comment: @Xanne If I were in a pedantic mood, I'd say your order is backwards. The right inside flap is usually given first when describing the parts of a dust jacket, since that's how they're designed and printed (and very few people apart from the designers and printers have much of a need to list the parts to begin with).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's indeed how they would appear laid flat. The back-flap is the part the tucks into the back cover of the book (CMS terminology).

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess what you're quoting is a review of a detective novel.

The first sentence sets it up and lets us know that Mr. Scudder is the detective.

The second sentence tells us this is the copy on the back-flap (jacket copy on a book) of a murder mystery--you guessed it! (This is an indirect way of suggesting that you'll enjoy trying to figure out the story as you read it.)

Then we get the author and title of the book.